# Linked List For Abstract Classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, linked-list, polymorphism

I am trying to create a linked list of an interface class and having problems with that.
I am having trouble trying to write a copy constructor and an assignment operator overload for the list.

Here are all the header files https://gist.github.com/itsuzair/4b34fb5d430cbdbaf748fb05908ac87f

My base class is `Device`
And `Computer` and `Mobile` are two classes inherited from it

I have a `Store` class in which I have two pointers to `Device` type which will be two linked lists for available and sold devices.

Here's the code for `addDevice` function

```
void Store::addDevice(int type, int ID, int memSize, int storageSize, int processorSpeed, int screenSize, bool a, bool b, bool c, bool d) {
    if (type == 1) {
        addMobile(availableDevices, ID, memSize, storageSize, processorSpeed, screenSize, a, b, c);
    } else {
        addPC(availableDevices, ID, memSize, storageSize, processorSpeed, screenSize, a, b, c, d);
    }
}
```

and the `addMobile` function

```
void addMobile(Device* &devices, int ID, int memSize, int storageSize, int processorSpeed, int screenSize, bool hasNetAdapter, bool hasCamera, bool hasMic) {
    if (devices == nullptr) {
        devices = new Mobile(ID, memSize, storageSize, processorSpeed, screenSize, hasNetAdapter, hasCamera, hasMic);
    } else {
        Device* temp = devices;
        while (temp->next != nullptr) {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = new Mobile(ID, memSize, storageSize, processorSpeed, screenSize, hasNetAdapter, hasCamera, hasMic);
    }
}
```

In this case when calling the function I pass the type parameter and call respective function for that device type.

Apart from copy constructor and assignment operator I am having problem trying to figure out a method to determine the type of node it is in the linked list.

As the node can be either of Mobile or Computer it's impossible to distinguish without explicitly storing it.

So say I have the `sellDevice()` function in which I want to remove the item from `availableDevices` list and add it to `soldDevices` list I cannot do that because I don't know what type of Device it is.

I'll loop through the availableDevices list and find device with required id but then I have to create a new object of either Mobile or Computer type in soldDevices list but it's impossible as I don't know the type.

And if I keep a type variable in my Device class then even though I'll be able to identify the object type but then since the list is of Device type I cannot access members of child class i.e Mobile/Computer.

Also I'd like to know if it's possible to create a copy constructor for interface classes (In my case the Device class)

I'd greatly appreciate any help in this regard,
Thanks !

Comment: This may help you: [clone pattern](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/18757/)

Comment: The presence of operator new is disturbing. So is rolling your own linked list class.  In any case, you need to post a MCVE before we can help much. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks @Oliv I'll take a look at that.

Comment: Links are not allowed in questions. Please read up about how to ask questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: @JiveDadson I know some things might not be upto the standards but this is a school assignment and we're to use our code and implementation of a data structure. I'll try to post a MCVE as per your posted link , Thanks

Comment: I hope it's an advanced class. In an introductory class you should not be fooling around with operator new.

Comment: For a linked list you ought to use `std::list` (or even better (in most cases, unless you *need* the semantics of a list) a `std::vector`). Messing around with manual memory management is usually a bad idea unless you are actually *implementing* those containers (but why would you unless you are a standard library maintainer?) or have a *really good* reason (and then do so very carefully). Just use the standard library containers.